# Is back-end access not required for an app to post to my blog?

Tags: login, posting, third-party-applications

I've recently installed a couple of apps (WordPress and BlogPad Pro) and I'm a bit surprised to see that they can indeed post to my blogs, even though I haven't given them the renamed login and wp-admin pages that I set up through iThemes Security.

My understanding was that posting could only happen "through" the back end of the blog; i.e. if you couldn't log into the blog through the login page, you couldn't post to the blog either. But evidently, with my username and password, these apps *can* post to the blog.

How does the app know to get "around" the obscured login page to post to the blog?

Comment: Obscurity got almost nothing to do with real security. The "obsxurity" feature of ithemes security is no more then snake oil.

Comment: Strong passwords are the main thing. If you got a weak password and you are trying to obscure the usual login path, to gain some "extra" security, then the bots can just work on your xml-prc access instead ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clients typically use [XML-RPC Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support).

If you take a look at your page source you will likely see endpoint declaration:

```
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://example.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://example.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
```

Apps are using this information and your credentials to access the site. In this way they can either discover location of admin or work without it altogether via XML-RPC.

Comment: IIRC it is also reported as an http header

Comment: Thanks -- I think I understand. So (a) does this pose a significant security risk (i.e. should I turn XML-RPC off), and if I do, (b) can these apps function at all without it? I'm enjoying the convenience of mobile blogging, but not at the cost of easy exploits.

Comment: @mattshepherd precisely no more or less than using WordPress admin. Obviously if client works over that protocol then turning it off will make it unable to.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not required. WordPress support this kind of *remote publishing* through the [`XML-RPC` interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) of your blog:

```
             XML-RPC calls
      APP ------------------> Your Blog (example.com/xmlrpc.php)
```

The app isn't accessing your blog through the usual `wp-login.php` door, instead it's talking to your `xmlprc.php` file in the language of `XML`.

The the `xmlrpc.php` file is located in your WordPress root folder.

If you want to turn off the XML-RPC access, it's possible with this single line of code:

```
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

You can read more about this in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support).